# Tag files Vs INCLUDE_PATH in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I have two C++ code projects, one (A) depends on the other (B). I want documentation generated for A to know about the types used from B. Adding B on INCLUDE_PATH doesn't seem to really do much so I'm generating a TAG for B and then added that into A. But is that the right way of doing things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer after further investigation is that INCLUDE_PATH doesn't as the name suggests add files to be documented by doxygen, only to be preprocessed.